# What is the difference between nf_table and xt_table?

Tags: linux, iptables, nftables

There are two sets of modules in linux netfilter framework.

One with nf prefix (e.g. nf_tables), another with xt prefix (e.g. xt_ecn).
What is the difference between two of them?

Answer (score 0):

The upstream Linux kernel firewall / packet filtering project is https://www.netfilter.org and most of the core modules supplied by that project have been named (and/or renamed) to include `nf` prefix.

Since the project provides among others both [*ip*tables](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/index.html) and [*nf*tables](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/index.html) they also use the  *X*tables collective name for the IPv4, IPv6, arp and eb toolsets.
That has resulted in selecting module names with the `xt` prefix.

[Xtables-addons](http://xtables-addons.sourceforge.net/) contains extensions that were not, or are not yet, accepted in the main kernel/iptables packages. Those also use the `xt` prefix.

Comment: The xtables-addons are not the only kernel modules that begin with `xt`. It might be better to say that those _also_ use the `xt` prefix.